# An app Can't be connected to Facebook

Tags: logging

I installed an app (GRE preparation) from Play Store, but when I tried to log in, this message appeared:

> For your account security, logging in to Facebook from an embedded
> browser is disabled. You may be able to continue by updating the app
> you're logging in from and trying again.

[image]

The app is the latest version and it works fine on my another device (Android 8.1, the one I'm using is 11). How to solve this problem? I've tried some tips I got from YouTube without success. I ask this as a general question, because I also encountered this problem when I installed another app, that means, the problem is on my phone.

Link app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.galvanizetestprep.vocabbuilder

Comment: Looks like this is not something that an end-user can fix, since it's developer-related: [Meta for Developers - For Your Account Security Logging Into From An Embedded Browser Is Disabled](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/195638179128499/). One of the posts linked to an announcement about [Deprecating support for FB Login authentication on Android embedded browsers](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/06/28/deprecating-support-fb-login-authentication-android-embedded-browsers/) since October 5, 2021.

Comment: Perhaps the one on Android 8.1 is still working because you have logged in with your Facebook account before the deprecation. I don't want you to risk this, but if you log out on Android 8.1, then try to log in again, I'm afraid you will face the same issue.